# What is the name of the track at 17:25 in episode 764 of One Piece?

Tags: one-piece, music

What's the name of the music track that plays at 17:25 where Brook play in episode 764 of *One Piece*?

Answer (score 0):

According to [this website](http://onepiecetracklist.com/), it's "Gold and Oden" (probably the second part?). You can search for the episode and click on a entry to see more information about a track.